# Horizontal timeline missing dots

Tags: html, css

I've used some code from [CSS Timeline Example](http://codepen.io/agrimsrud/pen/vtoqy).

I've tweaked each element in the CSS so that I can style all elements with `class="timeline"` because I have other `li` elements elsewhere that I don't want to modify. However I've gone wrong somewhere and I'm missing the dots and the arrow. What do I need to change please?

My CSS:

```css
/* ---- Timeline ---- */

ol.timeline {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin: 100px;
 height: 4px;
 background: #9b2;
}
ol::before.timeline,
ol::after.timeline {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: -8px;
 display: block;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
 border: 10px solid #9b2;
}
ol::before.timeline {
 left: -5px;
}
ol::after.timeline {
 right: -10px;
 border: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 0;
 border-left: 20px solid #9b2;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

/* ---- Timeline elements ---- */

li.timeline {
 position: relative;
 top: -77px;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 width: 150px;
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
 font: bold 14px arial;
}
li::before.timeline {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 3px;
 left: -29px;
 display: block;
 width: 6px;
 height: 6px;
 border: 4px solid #9b2;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: #eee;
}

/* ---- Details ---- */

.details {
 display: none;

 position: absolute;
 left: -85px;
 top: 60px;
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 border-right: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 font: 12px arial;
 background: #fff;
}
.details::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 left: 10px;
 top: -9px;
 display: block;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom-color: #fff;
 border-top: 0;
}

/* ---- Hover effects ---- */

li:hover.timeline {
 cursor: pointer;
  color: #28e;
}
li:hover::before.timeline {
 top: 1px;
 left: -31px;
 width: 8px;
 height: 8px;
 border-width: 5px;
 border-color: #28e;
}
li:hover.timeline .details {
 display: block;
  color: #444;
}
```

```html
 <ol class="timeline">
  <li class="timeline">
    Point 1
    <span class="details">
      Description of point 1
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="timeline">
    Point 2
    <span class="details">
      Description of point 2
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="timeline">
    Point 3
    <span class="details">
      Description of point 3
    </span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`li::before.timeline` isn't valid. you may mean to use

```
li.timeline::before
```

This is the case for multiple instances in your css.

This is because your pseudo element (whether that be the `::before` or `::after` element) **must be placed after** your 'selector'

---

Please also note you may wish to alter your pseudo element declaration to

```
li.timeline:before
```

i.e. remove the second colon as this increases browser compatibility on older browsers.

---

**Demo:**

```css
/* ---- Timeline ---- */

ol.timeline {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 100px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #9b2;
}
ol.timeline:before,
ol.timeline:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 10px solid #9b2;
}
ol.timeline:before {
  left: -5px;
}
ol.timeline:after {
  right: -10px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid #9b2;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
/* ---- Timeline elements ---- */

li.timeline {
  position: relative;
  top: -77px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  font: bold 14px arial;
}
li.timeline:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: -29px;
  display: block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border: 4px solid #9b2;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #eee;
}
/* ---- Details ---- */

.details {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -85px;
  top: 60px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  font: 12px arial;
  background: #fff;
}
.details:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: -9px;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
  border-top: 0;
}
/* ---- Hover effects ---- */

li.timeline:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #28e;
}
li.timeline:hover:before {
  top: 1px;
  left: -31px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: #28e;
}
li.timeline:hover .details {
  display: block;
  color: #444;
}
```

```html
<ol class="timeline">
  <li class="timeline">
    Point 1
    <span class="details">
      Description of point 1
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="timeline">
    Point 2
    <span class="details">
      Description of point 2
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="timeline">
    Point 3
    <span class="details">
      Description of point 3
    </span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

---

**further Reading**

- [Before Element](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-elements/:before)
- [hover pseudo selector](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:hover)

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your class correctly before the ::before selector.

You have

```
li::before.timeline
```

Which will not work instead you need

```
li.timeline::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: -29px;
    display: block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border: 4px solid #9b2;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #eee;
}
```

See a working example here http://jsfiddle.net/yevcnctu/1/

Its probably a good idea to check out more information at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp